# C# Export to Excel giving '', hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character error

Tags: c#, row

> giving '', hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character error

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in data.Rows)
    {
         row = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row { RowIndex =+rowcount};
         for (int i = 0; i < fieldsToExpose.Length; i++)
            {
               row.Append(CreateTextCell(ColumnLetter(i), rowcount,dataRow[fieldsToExpose[i]].ToString()));
            }
             sheetData.AppendChild(row);
     }
 worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
```

> Getting error when saving the worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save() because 'row' contains the hexadecimal value

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Can you reduce your data that you are looping through so that you can track down what portion of it is actually causing the problem? Is it a particular cell, or is it endemic throughout the spreadsheet?

Comment: Is the data unicode or binary?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some invalid XML text. you can check it by using below statement:

```cs
System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(dataRow[fieldsToExpose[i]].ToString())
```

Use the below code:

```cs
row.Append(
  CreateTextCell(
    ColumnLetter(i), 
    rowcount, 
    Regex.Replace(
      dataRow[fieldsToExpose[i]].ToString(), 
      @"[\u0000-\u0008\u000A-\u001F\u0100-\uFFFF]", 
      ""
    )
  )
);
```